# How to add an xml tag based on specific condition using python

Tags: python

**sample XML File**

```
<ArticleSet>
    <Article>
        <ForeName>a</ForeName>
        <LastName>b</LastName>
        <Affiliation>harvard university of science. abc@gmail.com</Affiliation>
        <Keywords>-</Keywords>
    </Article>
    <Article>
        <ForeName>a</ForeName>
        <LastName>b</LastName>
        <Affiliation>-</Affiliation>
        <Keywords>-</Keywords>
    </Article>
    <Article>
        <ForeName>a</ForeName>
        <LastName>b</LastName>
        <Affiliation>harvard university of science. ghi@yahoo.co.in</Affiliation>
        <Keywords>-</Keywords>
    </Article>
</ArticleSet>
```

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as etree
import re

root = etree.parse("sampleinput.xml").getroot()

for article in root.iter("Affiliation"):
    if(article.text != "-"):
        email = re.search(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', article.text)
        c = etree.Element("<Email>")
        c.text = email.group(0)
        etree.write(article,c)
```

**OUTPUT REQUIRED UPDATED XML FILE**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArticleSet>
    <Article>
        <ForeName>a</ForeName>
        <LastName>b</LastName>
        <Affiliation>harvard university of science. abc@gmail.com</Affiliation>
        <Keywords>-</Keywords>
        <Email>abc@gmail.com</Email>
    </Article>
    <Article>
        <ForeName>a</ForeName>
        <LastName>b</LastName>
        <Affiliation>-</Affiliation>
        <Keywords>-</Keywords>
        <Email>-</Email>
    </Article>
    <Article>
        <ForeName>a</ForeName>
        <LastName>b</LastName>
        <Affiliation>harvard university of science. ghi@yahoo.co.in</Affiliation>
        <Keywords>-</Keywords>
        <Email>ghi@yahoo.co.in</Email>
    </Article>
</ArticleSet>
```

I want to extract email address from `<Affiliation>` tag and make a new tag named `<Email>` and store extracted email into that tag. If `<Affiliation>` is equal to `-` then store `<Email>-</Email>` into that article.

**ERROR**

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/Ghost Rider/Documents/Python/addingTagsToXML.py", line 11, in 
>       etree.write(article,c)
>   AttributeError: module 'xml.etree.ElementTree' has no attribute 'write'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

```
import re
import xml
tree = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse('filename.xml')
e = tree.getroot()

for article in e.findall('Article'):
    child = xml.etree.ElementTree.Element("Email")
    if article[2].text != '-':
        email = re.search(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', article[2].text).group()
        child.text = email
    else:
        child.text = ' - '
    article.insert(4,child)
tree.write("filename.xml")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `write` you should correct the etree import like this:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
```

And you shouldn't use `etree` as an alias for ElementTree because it will overwtrite the `etree` python builtin module!

Furthermore I think you misinterpret the meaning of the `write` function, because it can only write the result tree to a file. If you want to modify an elemtree you should use something like `append`, `extend` etc. on your Element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use lxml instance xml library.This code is working fine

```
import re
from lxml import etree as et
# Open original file
tree = et.parse('t.xml')
for article in tree.iter("Affiliation"):
    if(article.text != "-"):
        email = re.search(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', article.text)
        child = et.SubElement(article.getparent(), 'Email')
        child.text = email.group(0)
    else:
        child = et.SubElement(article.getparent(), 'Email')
        child.text = ' - '

# Write back to file
tree.write('t.xml')
```